# How to make view react on click

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created custom widget which inherits View.

```
<com.test.www.view.ElementView
    android:id="@+id/surface1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"

/
```

>

and

```
public class ElementView extends View {
    private final int width=100;
    private final int height=100;
    private Paint paint=null;
    private Canvas canvas=null;

    public ElementView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public ElementView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        paint = new Paint();
    }


    public ElementView(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defaultStyles) {
        super(context, attr, defaultStyles);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        int measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        int measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(this.width,this.height);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas=canvas;
        // get the size of your control based on last call to onMeasure
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();

        // Now create a paint brush to draw your widget

        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        //define border
        this.canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 99, paint);
        this.canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 99,0, paint);
        this.canvas.drawLine(99, 0, 99, 99, paint);
        this.canvas.drawLine(0, 99, 99,99, paint);

        //define cells
        this.canvas.drawLine(0,50,99,50,paint);
        this.canvas.drawLine(30,0,30,50,paint);

        //draw green rectangle
        this.canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,50,50),paint);
        //draw some text
        paint.setTextSize(8);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        String displayText = "test";


        Float textWidth = paint.measureText(displayText);

        int px = width / 2;
        int py = height / 2;
        this.canvas.drawText(displayText, px - textWidth / 2, py, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        //change color of first cell
        canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,50,50),paint);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

Problem is that this ElementView doesn't react on click. I have override of dispatch event but it doesn't come in. Can anybody help me ? What to do to make this ElementView react on click ?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do something like this:

```
ElementView ev = (ElementView)findViewById(R.id.surface1);
ev.setOnClickListener(evOnClick);

public OnClickListener evOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v, int arg1) {
    //DO ONCLICK STUFF
  }
};
```

I'm not sure if you can actually put the onClick inside the view definition like you are trying to, but Id like if someone could show me how.

Comment: Thanks, it enters now but I cannot change color ! It pas through code but view stays the same.

Comment: Maybe in ElementView create a public function to handle color change. Then call that function in the onClick: ev.changeColor(someVar);

Comment: You might try calling invalidate() on the view at the end of processing the onClick stuff, forcing it to redraw.